# Sharing memory between processes on different computers

Tags: sockets, architecture, shared-memory

Can someone help me with sharing memory between three or more machines, each machine having its own copy of the memory to speed up the read operation

For example, I first create a socket to communicate between these processes, but how can I make memory visible between the machines? I know how make it visible in one machine.

EDIT: Maybe we should use server machine to manage shared memory read and write operation?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot share memory across machine boundaries.  You have to serialize the data being shared, such as with an IPC mechanism like a named pipe or a socket.  Transmit the shared data to each machine, where they then copy it into their own local memory.  Any changes to the local memory has to be transmitted to the other machines so they have an updated local copy.

If you are having problems implementing that, they you need to show what you have actually attempted.